# path bindable date play framework

Tags: playframework, simpledateformat

I am attempting to pass a date through a route in my play framework app, which I am quite new to. After many hours i am now trying t get a pathbindable to work with the code below however whenever I run it I always get bad request with the "invalid date format blah blah" How can i get this to successfully pass the date to the controller? Please help

```
package libs

import java.util.Date
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import play.api.mvc.PathBindable
import scala.util.{Either, Failure, Success, Try}

object PathBinders {

  implicit def bindableDate(implicit stringBinder: PathBindable[String]) = new PathBindable[Date] {

    val sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM ddd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy")

    override def bind(key: String, value: String): Either[String, Date] = {
      for {
        dateString <- stringBinder.bind(key, value).right
        date <- Try(sdf.parse(dateString)).toOption.toRight("Invalid date format blah blah.").right
      } yield date
    }

    override def unbind(key: String, date: Date): String = key + "=" + sdf.format(date)

  }

}
```

The format of it I have tried multiple different methods but in my app the page before I am successfully displaying the date as Thu May 10 00:00:00 BST 2018. This is coming from an ebean model which is linked to a SQL database.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following to handle date information coming from `views` into `controller` method:

1. Have a route and pass it as a query string:

   ```
   POST   /passDate  controllers.date.request(datetime: String)
   ```
2. Pass it through the request, as it is not secure related it could be within the path (need to replace space with `-` or whatever valid URL character):

   ```
   /passDate?datetime=1-1-1970
   ```
3. Within the request, split the `datetime` query string, and putting back together:

   ```
   scala> "Thu May 10 00:00:00 BST 2018".split(' ').toList
   res1: List[String] = List(Thu, May, 10, 00:00:00, BST, 2018)
   ```
4. Then based on the location within the list you know what is the datetime information and you can turn them to any string literal and parsing it. For example:

   ```
   scala>  val formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
   formater: java.text.SimpleDateFormat = java.text.SimpleDateFormat@4f76f1b0

   scala> formatter.parse("2018-08-01 14:58:00")
   res2: java.util.Date = Wed Aug 01 14:58:00 BST 2018
   ```